# Should a project build successfully after check out from SVN?

Tags: svn

Whenever I checkout projects from our SVN, they never build.
 Either because they are accessing old libraries in the GAC that I don't have installed in my development machine.
 Or because they have are pointing to externals that have changed over time.
 Or they just don't have the required dlls included in the project bin.

My question is, is it best practice to always make sure the project always builds successfully? Or is this only required on a case by case basis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

(I need to enter more characters, but there really is no reason too... It is undisputed best practice that checking out the source and running a single command should build your project)

William Pursell makes some excellent points.  I truly do believe the answer is as simple as a yes.  However checking in dlls to svn is nearly as bad as having to scavanger hunt for them.
There of course will be assumptions about the toolchain - it's not appropriate to check in a compiler or something like glibc that would be handled by the package manager on your machine.

To elaborate :

1. A new team member should be able to follow the doc on how to install the required tooling check out the source and run the build.
2. Achieving number one by checking in binaries (dlls or jars) to svn is going to lead to a bad time.
3. How you get those required libraries is pretty platform and toolchain specific.  It's entirely a solved problem in java (maven and ant/ivy) and .NET has decent support with nuget.  I've worked with systems that used mixes of these tools that even worked with old school c++ to get libraires like boost.   The important takeaway is that there be some kind of manifest checked in with the source that describes these dependencies and how to resolve them.

It can be done, and there may be large value in it.

Comment: So if the project has a dependency, all of the source code for that dependency should be in the repository?  So the source code for glibc, ncurses, python, etc. must be in the repository?  I truly do not understand this position.  It is absurd to include all dependencies in every repository, and is certainly not best practice to do so, yet I continually see people argue this position.  These seem incompatible to me.

Comment: I never mentioned anything about putting any the dependencies in the source repository.  Checking in any binaries is a really bad idea, particularly with a DVCS system (git, hg, etc). Of course there are expected tools someone would have to install before building (compilers or interpreters.).  Any libraries that are needed should be fetched with a dependency manager (maven, ivy, nuget, etc).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very subjective question, so there are many answers.  However, dependency tracking and resolution is a problem best solved by a package management tool.  A version control system is not a package management tool and it is (in my opinion) a huge mistake to try to use it as such.  Should a project build from the vcs?  Yes, on a developer's box which has satisfied all the dependencies.  Should it build from scratch on an arbitrary system?  No.  That is what the release tarball is for.  Many projects like to use the VCS as a primary system of deployment, which confuses the issue.  A VCS should be used to track the history of the software, not to deploy or resolve dependencies.  So, I believe the answer is a qualified "no".

Answer (score 0):

Let's frame this a little bit

*Yes*, there should be a way to get the sources to build, ideally from simple, well-maintained instructions within the repository itself; typically, `INSTALL` or `README` in the top level of the repo. There needs to be a person whose job it is to make sure this exists, and is up to date.

But *no*, it is not reasonable to require every check-in on every branch to satisfy this requirement. It is a good requirement for a "production" or "stable" branch, and again, a documented policy would be ideal.